# Merging OpenLayers3 overlay with a get feature on click command that closes

Tags: javascript, openlayers, overlay, getfeatureinfo

I have [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/Lkj54mwa/3/) that is working fine on its own to select cities in the UK.

I have then taken this OpenLayers3 example and put it into [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/cdh9dby2/1/).

I am looking to combine the two so I have a close button and some other text when I click on each city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there it is, your [fiddle forked and merged](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/j8zhc9pt/1/).

You get rid of jquery popover and implement Openlayers popup:

```
content.innerHTML = feature.get('name');
popup.setPosition(coord);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonatas, is it just me or does the popup only appear when you click slightly off to the left?

Comment: Same here. Some offset on feature.

Comment: Changed it to an icon and altered the CSS and got it working nicely now thanks: http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/j8zhc9pt/3/

Comment: You're welcome. Much better.